# Android Facebook loginResult denies email permission

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

Facebook sdk is denying automatically email permission

I am calling logIn like this

```
loginManager.logIn(fragment, listOf(EMAIL))
```

this is the registerCallback

```
loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
  override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
    Timber.v("onSuccess")

    Timber.v("recentlyDeniedPermissions %s", result?.recentlyDeniedPermissions)
    Timber.v("recentlyGrantedPermissions %s", result?.recentlyGrantedPermissions)
  }

  override fun onCancel() {
    Timber.v("onCancel")
  }

  override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
    Timber.w(error, "error while login with Facebook")
  }
})
```

and once user accepts, loginResult comes like this

```
onSuccess
recentlyDeniedPermissions [email]
recentlyGrantedPermissions [public_profile]
```

facebook sdk never asks for email, just for public profile

[image: Facebook login sdk]

I'm using kotlin, androidX, com.facebook.android:facebook-login:11.1.0, compileSdkVersion 30, minSdkVersion 26, targetSdkVersion 30

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't enabled email permission in the facebook application

[image]